# Can't run groovy script in Groovy Grails Tool Suite

Tags: eclipse, groovy

I installed Groovy Grails Tool Suite Version: 3.5.0.RELEASE on a Windows system.

I have created a new 'Groovy' project using the eclipse Groovy project wizard.  My project contains one script called 'HelloGroovy.groovy'.  When I right click on my script, and choose 'Run As', I do not see any option to run my script except for 'Run Configurations'.  I want to see a groovy script option instead.  Is there something I need to do to set up my ide further?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that you have a space in the path to your workspace. I just tried recreating your situation and when there is no space, it works. When there is a space (e.g. `C:\Documents and Settings\Foo\Bar\workspace`) the menu option doesn't show. I raised https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRECLIPSE-1737 to cover fixing it.